# Can't update database inside of ruby loop

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sinatra, datamapper

This code displays the signup, which shows data.

```
 cids.each {|c_array|
    puts c_array[0]
    signup = Signup.first(:customer_id => c_array[0])
    #signup.created_at = c_array[1]
    puts "signup is " + signup.inspect
    #signup.update!
  }
```

Result:

```
signup is #<Signup @id=1 @user_id=1 @customer_id=74843293 @company_id=6 @created_at=Thu, 08 Jan 2015 22:21:43 -0500 @updated_at=Thu, 08 Jan 2015 22:21:43 -0500>

signup is #<Signup @id=2 @user_id=1 @customer_id=67170279 @company_id=6 @created_at=Thu, 08 Jan 2015 22:21:43 -0500 @updated_at=Thu, 08 Jan 2015 22:21:43 -0500>

signup is #<Signup @id=3 @user_id=1 @customer_id=69079324 @company_id=6 @created_at=Thu, 08 Jan 2015 22:21:44 -0500 @updated_at=Thu, 08 Jan 2015 22:21:44 -0500>

signup is #<Signup @id=4 @user_id=1 @customer_id=60434274 @company_id=6 @created_at=Thu, 08 Jan 2015 22:21:44 -0500 @updated_at=Thu, 08 Jan 2015 22:21:44 -0500>
```

And so forth.

But when I uncomment the other two lines:

```
 cids.each {|c_array|
    puts c_array[0]
    signup = Signup.first(:customer_id => c_array[0])
    signup.created_at = c_array[1]
    puts "signup is " + signup.inspect
    signup.update!
  }
```

It breaks:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `created_at=' for nil:NilClass:
    customerController.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in <class:CustomerController>'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: wrap signup.update in flow control.  `signup ? signup.update! : puts c_array[0]`  Your array has a value your database doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you don't always have `Signup` with `customer_id` from your array and sometimes it returns `nil` instead of `Signup` object. Simply add a following check:

```
cids.each do |c_array|
  puts c_array[0]
  signup = Signup.first(:customer_id => c_array[0])
  puts "signup is " + signup.inspect
  unless signup.nil?
    signup.created_at = c_array[1]  
    signup.update!
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you @Rustam. Your solution made perfect sense. I just had to modify it slightly to do the update on one line. ```signup.update(:created_at => c_array[1])``` and remove ```signup.update!```. It had been a long day and I needed to rest. :)